# How to give cell texlabel animation as in music player

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to animate table view cell text label.When user long press the cell the text should start moving from right to left as in music player (the name of song is moving from right to left).
Thanks for help

Comment: Where is your attempt on implementing this yourself. Your question as it stands looks like a code request, which is frowned up and might get your question down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do you need to disable selection for the tableView.

Add this on viewDidLoad: `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;`

after that add gesture recognizer to the labels:

```
cell.label = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction:)];
[self.longPressGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[cell.label addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

As for the Label, it should be wider than the width of the screen and only 1 line (that way the text will disappear).

```
- (void)gestureAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


      //in here you add the code with animation to move the position of the label

}
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the code a but and add delegate to my view controller and it is OK, can you tell me please how to do the animation? Because I don't understand it.